# Bootstrap 4 Grid elements are not in the same horizontal line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I am using Bootstrap 4.0 [Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) in Angular to create a layout.

But I got this:

[image]

It seems that the text in the orange box is not in the same horizontal line with others' content.

This is my code:

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
      <nav>
        <a routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active">Dashboard</a>
        <a routerLink="/users" routerLinkActive="active">Users</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2" [hidden]="!login.online">
      <span>
        {{login.userName}}
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2" [hidden]="!login.online">
        <span >
            <button class="btn btn-light" (click)="login.logout()">Logout</button>
        </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What's wrong with it?

I simplified the question, see https://jsfiddle.net/Belter/8Ld3nw2t/2/

I want all the text at the same horizontal line

Comment: Can you make JSfiddle?

Comment: Try with below codes,Because your jsfiddle code not having bootstrap plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can override this:

HTML

```
<span id="username_id">
     {{login.userName}}
</span>
```

CSS

```
#username_id {
     padding: 0dp;
     margin: 0dp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case,inside the span tag button tag is there,So its showing vertically center of all buttons.
{{login.userName}} is only contains in span tag.We need to set span tag property for make **vertical-align CSS** property.

And **col-2 and col-8** is not working,try to add **col-lg-2 and col-lg-8**,your code may be bootstrap version not connected.

```
.col-2 span{vertical-align:sub}
```

Try with this codes.

Comment: This url is work, https://jsfiddle.net/Belter/8Ld3nw2t/2/, but your method is not work

Answer (score 0):

The padding of the `btn` is making the row taller. The other text span doesn't have padding so it naturally stays at the top. Use the [padding utils](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) (eg. `py-3`) to adjust the col with the `span`...

https://www.codeply.com/go/Q29TK0nEuF

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
            <nav>
                <a class="btn btn-light" routerlink="/dashboard" routerlinkactive="active">Dashboard</a>
                <a class="btn btn-light" routerlink="/users" routerlinkactive="active">Users</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 py-2" [hidden]="!login.online">
            <span>
                {{login.userName}}
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2" [hidden]="!login.online">
            <span>
                <button class="btn btn-light" (click)="login.logout()">Logout</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```